# how to increase the ulimit limit in ubuntu 18?

Tags: command-line

I want to increase the ulimits and used the commands for it

```
ulimit -n
1024
ulimit -n 10000
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

After lot of searching. I got a my links but By taking the reference of [this](https://gist.github.com/luckydev/b2a6ebe793aeacf50ff15331fb3b519d) link I just follow each and every command in the terminal but can't increase the ulimit in the system why and How will I do it Can anybody please explain this.

Comment: Your question and title don't seem to match. Can you fix either or explain the relation, please? It would also be helpful if you pasted those exact commands you ran directly into your question, together with their output, if there was any. Did you actually log out or reboot after changing these values, as described in your link?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!! try use it as root, and type `ulimit -n 20000` and check it using `ulimit -a`

Comment: from  logout or reboot your mean close the terminal and reopen it again?@ByteCommander

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without `Sudo` or `Root` privileges?
Also -

There are two kinds of limits:

- **Soft** limits are simply the currently enforced limits
- **Hard** limits mark the maximum value which cannot be exceeded by setting a soft limit

Soft limits could be set by any user while hard limits are changeable only by root. Limits are a property of a process. They are inherited when a child process is created so system-wide limits should be set during the system initialization in init scripts and user limits should be set during user login for example by using pam_limits.

There are often defaults set when the machine boots. So, even though you may reset your ulimit in an individual shell, you may find that it resets back to the previous value on reboot. You may want to grep your boot scripts for the existence ulimit commands if you want to change the default.

Comment: with `sudo` commands it gives the error of `command not find` and with `root` `it does not found`

Comment: sorry my bad, try without `sudo` and without `root`.
try just `ulimit -n 1025` and check?

Comment: i want to increase it to 10000 not to 1025

Comment: it works for me, I really dont know why it doesn't work for you.
I just tried `ulimit -n 10000`
Just press CTRL+D and log back into shell and try?

Comment: If you are using Linux and you got the permission error, you will need to raise the allowed limit in the  /etc/limits.conf or /etc/security/limits.conf file (where the file is located depends on your specific Linux distribution).

For example to allow anyone on the machine to raise their number of open files up to 10000 add the line to the limits.conf file.

* `hard nofile 10000`

Then logout and relogin to your system and you should be able to do:

`ulimit -n 10000`

without a permission error.